# RxJava zip operator to make15+ network call in background

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

```
    private fun getAllFollowers(user: User){
    val items = user.items
    val requests = ArrayList<Observable<List<Followers>>>()
    for (item in items!!.iterator()) {
        requests.add(AutoCompleteApiProvider.getFollowersList(item.followersUrl))
    }
    //here ZIP is not resolving
    Observable.zip(requests, Function<ArrayList<Followers>,java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<Followers>>>(){
        var allResponse = java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<Followers>>()
        allResponse.add(it)
        return@Function allResponse
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(Action1<ArrayList<ArrayList<Followers>>> { time -> Log.d(TAG, "I will call adapter here") },
                    Action1<Throwable> { throwable ->  Log.d(TAG, "error handing part here")})

}
```

here zip operator is not resolving. I am not sure that i am passing right params to zip operator.

I want to perform following task.
Search for users by their name using the GitHub API (sorted by the
number of followers) and display the results in a RecyclerView

so As user type in editText, I am calling Github API which gives username suggestion but I want to sort this name as per the number of followers each name has.
to get followers to count I need to make separate Github API call with userName as query params and API will respond with followers object. I will count this followers object.

here the tricky part is if search suggestion API gives 30 users in response.
I will have to make 30 network call parallelly and will have to wait until the response of each API call. once I have 30 response than I will count followers of each user and perform followers wise sorting and shows the result in recyclerview

so once I have username suggestion. I make API call to get followers using rxJava ZIP operator. 
I am making a list of `Observable<List<Followers>>` and passing this list to zip operator here my question which function I should pass as second args in zip operators. any suggestion around this?

rest code is complete but i stuck at zip operator.

Comment: The signature of the function is `Function<Object[], R>` in Java. Use the equivalent type definition in Kotlin.

Comment: can you write signature of Fucntion in java for my use case? Return type will be ArrayList<ArrayList<Followers>>

Comment: I leave it as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  variable requests is a ArrayList of observable
  val observableFun = Observable.zip(requests, Function<Array<Any>,
            HashMap<ItemsItem, ArrayList<Followers>>> { t ->
       /* write your own logic to play around combine response of all observalble*/
        return@Function allResponse
    })
```

and subscribe this observableFun.